# Как подавить "deprecated" для mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть хостинг (на котором, само собой, не добраться до настроек/опций сборки ПО), на котором мы споткнулись, что через mysqli работать не можем. При разборе полётов выяснилось, что на нём PHP Version 5.5.11 со следующими extensions:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cgi-fcgi
    [1] => core
    [2] => ctype
    [3] => date
    [4] => ereg
    [5] => filter
    [6] => gd
    [7] => json
    [8] => libxml
    [9] => mbstring
    [10] => mcrypt
    [11] => mysql
    [12] => openssl
    [13] => pcre
    [14] => reflection
    [15] => session
    [16] => simplexml
    [17] => spl
    [18] => standard
    [19] => tokenizer
    [20] => xml
    [21] => zend opcache
    [22] => zip
    [23] => zlib
)
```

Т.е. из баз данных выпилено всё (в т.ч. рекомендуемые mysqli и PDO), оставлен только mysql, который с PHP 5.5 печально помечен как Deprecated. При этом на хостинге вполне работает Bitrix, но при попытке запустить свой набор PHP-скриптов, используя методы mysql_*, вся работа с БД валится с ошибкой
Server.Answer.Error: [8192] mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
Как подавить эту ошибку, чтобы всё работало так же, как работает Bitrix? При беглом осмотре в Bitrix не найдено каких-либо заглушек а-ля [@mysql_](/users/13865/mysql_error) или error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED), да и нам эти фокусы с просторов инета не помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прописать в .htaccess значение error_reporting

[Тут пример файла .htaccess](http://aloha.kiev.ua/PHP-Error-htaccess-Nastrojki.html)

Comment: Очень интересная штука, но выяснилось, что с этим на хостинге облом.

Некоторые хостинги настроены с ограничением прав, из-за чего некоторые директивы вызывают 500 Internal Server Error, тогда могут помочь следующие действия:

 - директиву Options +FollowSymLinks заменить на Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

 - закомментировать параметр +ExecCGI

 - закомментировать директиву -MultiViews

 - закомментировать параметры AddHandler, php_value, php_flag - при комментировании этих параметров не работает настройка логгирования.

Comment: можно в самом скрипте написать ini_set() итд, но лучше поменять хостинг. непонятно почему  это может быть невозможно. Можно ещё им саппорт написать и рассказать, что вы думаете об их сексуальных предпочтениях, умственном развитии и то-же  самое о всех их начальниках.